MS Access - Operation must use an updateable query
I'm trying to update 5 columns on a table using the results of another query.  The SQL is below.  T used the other query to selet the RO numbers I need with out any issue.    I'm trying to join the table I want to update with the query that selects the RO Numbers.  However I'm getting an error that says Operation must use an updateable query.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance for your help.......
UPDATE ROtable INNER JOIN [MJS_Get ROs] ON ROtable.[Repair Order] = [MJS_Get ROs].REPR_ORDR_ID SET ROtable.Ul_Date = Date(), ROtable.UL_Empl = "12345", ROtable.UL_Grp = "A1", ROtable.UL_Br = "2C", ROtable.NoAllocation = "Not Allocated"
WHERE (((ROtable.NoAllocation) Is Null));


Why save these values to table? That is duplicating data. Run the SELECT query when needed. Show the SQL for [MJS_Get ROs]. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

@June7.......i have a macro that pulls records from the RO table based on these fields.  If they are blank, these records appear in the results, where the user performs some action and uodates the table based on that action.  This prevents uers from processing records multiple times.

@ June7......The process that updates the RO table was updated and there are records that should not be in this table. I'm trying to prevent significant customer supoort by updating specific recirds so they are not pulled into the macro results.  I'll show the sql later on this morning.  Thanks for the help

Example data as formatted text tables might be helpful as well. I still don't understand why data from one table needs to be saved to another. How does the duplicate question not resolve your issue?

@June7............Once a week, a process is run that gets new orders for the last 7 days.  The process splits the data into 2 tables.  One table requires user review and the other table doesn't.
The Process Owner modified the app this process runs against.  As a result, orders not needing review ended up in the "review" table; causing issues for users.  I'm identifying records that shouldn't be in the "review" table and updating 5 fields.  This prevent records from being extracted by the macro.  It makes these records, out of sight, out of mind and will not cause issues for our end users

@June7............this is the SQL I'm using to identify the records that should not be in the "review" table:
SELECT TransTable.REPR_ORDR_ID
FROM TransTable
WHERE (((TransTable.LOB_DSC)="DR") AND ((TransTable.SERV_TYP_DSC) In ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")))
GROUP BY TransTable.REPR_ORDR_ID;
This gets the list of Order numbers that needed to be updated in the "review" table.
Thanks for your help.///////

I expect the GROUP BY clause is preventing the UPDATE action. DISTINCT won't work either. This will require VBA looping recordset or saving the GROUP BY dataset to a table or maybe domain aggregate function. Or try the DISTINCTROW solution described in duplicate question.

Why doesn't "Process Owner" fix the process and prevent this issue to begin with? An alternative to UPDATE is to "move" records to the appropriate table. This would involve INSERT and DELETE actions. I really don't see need for two tables. A Status field in one table could identify records that need "review".
